# Jboss 4.2.3 with rest easy 2.3.2 - JNDI lookup fails

Tags: java, jboss, resteasy

I want to use JBoss 4.2.3 with RESTEasy 2.3.2. I'm able to do it by adding all the required Jars to library. This works fine when I don't use CDI capabilities.

However, if I try to use @Inject in the classes, the BeanManager lookup fails and therefore the deployment. From https://issues.jboss.org/browse/RESTEASY-558, I understand that this issue has been fixed.

- I'm using JDK 1.6.X
- I have beans.xml in my WEB-INF
- Tried with WELD servlet. But the final error remains same
- Added `<resource-env-ref>` to web.xml which did not work

## web.xml content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.0">
    <display-name>xyz</display-name>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServlet30Dispatcher</servlet-class>
</servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Resteasy</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.scan</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.resource.method-interceptors</param-name>
        <param-value>
         org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethodSecurityInterceptor
      </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ResteasyBootstrap</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>resteasy.injector.factory</param-name>
        <param-value>org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

## Stacktrace:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to lookup BeanManager.
        at org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory.lookupBeanManager(CdiInjectorFactory.java:131)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.cdi.CdiInjectorFactory.<init>(CdiInjectorFactory.java:41)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:355)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:308)
        at org.jboss.resteasy.spi.ResteasyDeployment.start(ResteasyDeployment.java:138)
```

## Questions:

- Is it possible for JBoss 4.2.3 to have CDI capabilities at all ?
- I see that JNDI lookup is failing. Who (which module/class) is responsible for adding the JNDI entry ?
- Is there any problem with web.xml I have ?

I'm stuck with this for past one day. Any help is truly appreciated.